# Adding /us/ permalink to every parmalink in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

What I want is very simple. I just want to add /us/ to every permalink in WordPress.

e.g: if a link is example.com/a-page/ or example.com/a-post/
I want it converted to example.com/us/a-page/ and example.com/us/a-post/ automatically.

/us/ should be added to every post, page, CPT, product, category, everything.

The simplest solution is to just put the entire WordPress in a /us directory. But I was wondering if there is a way I can do this without putting it in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace for that.

> Perform a regular expression search and replace

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
  function wp_custom_( $subject ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
      $search = [
        '/href="(.*?)\/"/',
        '/href="(.*?)"/',
        '/href=\'(.*?)\/\'/',
        '/href=\'(.*?)\'/',
        // ... etc.
      ];
      $replace = [
        'href="$1"',
        'href="$1/us/"',
        'href=\'$1\'',
        'href=\'$1/us/\'',
      ];
      $subject = preg_replace( $search, $replace, $subject );
      return $subject;
    };
  };
  ob_start( 'wp_custom_' );
} ); ?>
```

---

### Learn more

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php